# Should tag sentence or whole review for training set?

Tags: r, model, text-classification, training-data, naivebayes

I am new in analytics field. Maybe this question is silly for you. I am working on a review classification using `R`. I have to classify review into 50 different categories. I am manually tagging the data for training purpose of Model. I am bit confused how to tag the review?

What I am doing here is,
 first I converted single review into sentences and then give a specific category to these sentences. Am I doing right here?

Or I have to give the category tag to the review without breaking into sentences ? If the review falls under more than 1 category that time what should do ?

Comment: you need to generate features from the text before you train, what features are you generating now?

Comment: I am using bag of words

Answer (score 1):

Each review could have multiple labels. Whatever features you use for your classifier does not affect your labeling process.

Your labeled reviews (for training or evaluation) should look like this:

```
ID        Content                    Tags
review#1, "content of the review#1", Mexican food,spicy
review#2, "content of the review#2", American food,apple pie,dessert
```

where "Mexican food", "spicy", "apple pie", "dessert" and "American food" are all possible tags. For each review, you only need to provide those tags that apply. By default, we would assume that other tags do not apply.

At training time, you should choose a classifier that is working for [multi-label](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multilabel-classification-format).